# Static linking 64-bit glibc libraries into binary

Tags: linker, fortran, static-linking

So maybe this is me exposing my naivety in terms of linking and compiling.

I'm trying to compile some Fortran code such that it can run as a stand alone binary. One issue (among several) is that I want to compile on a system with GLIBC 2.14 but run on one with 2.11. Is it possible to statically link in libraries like GLIBC, or is that impossible because of the library's size?

My `Makefile` uses `-static`, `-static-libgcc`, and `-static-libgfortran` flags and the following compiler flags

```
-c -cpp -fall-intrinsics -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -std=f2003
```

However, when I use ldd on the output, I get

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff13b63000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007febfd7cf000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007febfd578000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007febfd362000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007febfd12c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007febfcd9c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007febfdae7000)
```

**Update**

The machine I'm compiling on is running openSUSE 12.2:

```
Linux 3.4.33-2.24-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

While the machine I'm trying to execute on is openSUSE 11.4:

```
Linux 2.6.37.6-24-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update 2**

I've re-written the makefile, and I'm trying to compile with ifort (the intel compiler) because it provides the static-intel flag which reduces some of the dependencies.

My ldd output is now

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff381ff000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f89b07cf000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f89b05b2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f89b0222000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f89b001e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f89b0a26000)
```

Using the following compiler flags

```
FCFLAGS = -cpp -static-intel -static-libgcc
```

The problem is if I do just `-static` (or `-static-intel -static`) then I get

```
ld: cannot find -lm
ld: cannot find -lpthread
ld: cannot find -lc
ld: cannot find -ldl
ld: cannot find -lc
make: *** [IDP] Error 1
```

Which I believe is because I don't have static versions of these libraries on my system

**UPDATE 3**

I also tried the approach of providing the shared objects in a library (as suggested by [this post])(https://stackoverflow.com/a/3214232/615257) but it just segmentation faults.

Comment: Static linking of `glibc` might be impossible because of licensing issues - they want to make sure any user of your program has the ability to use another library of their own choosing.

Comment: Yeah - I'm beginning to think that might be the case too. The hard thing is this isn't actually my code, so I'm re-writing the Makefile now to see if there's some issue where the flags are being ignored.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: The `-c` compiler option hints that you have a separate link step. What options get passed to the linker (sans the many object file names)? In my own test `gfortran -static -o test.exe test.f90` produces a truly static executable.

Comment: Why is it not possible to compile on the OpenSUSE 11.4 machine?

Comment: Well it is - which is what we're doing right now :-). I guess when I started I thought there'd be a quick fix, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This is a common problem.  All the later distributions from 2011 onwards do not have static versions of the 64-bit libraries.  They ship with the 32-bit versions but not with 64.  You just have to use the shared lib versions of libm, libc etc.

Comment: @cup You should post this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem. All the later distributions from 2011 onwards do not have static versions of the 64-bit libraries. They ship with the 32-bit versions but not with 64. You just have to use the shared lib versions of libm, libc etc.

Comment: @VladimirF Where did you get it from? I can find literally nothing on the web regarding how you obtain the static libraries.

Comment: From the package manager, package `glibc-devel-static'. http://software.opensuse.org/package/glibc-devel-static